# Shortcut key for opening export window?

Tags: sas, keyboard-shortcuts, uipath, rpa

i want to know is there any shortcut key for table export in output data window

right now if we want to export a table we have to do this `Output Data --> Right Click Table Name --> Share --> Export`

with this navigation it open the save window

is there any shortcut for opening the same save window while skipping the `Right Click Table Name --> Share --> Export`

this is about UiPath RPA  and not for sas in particular,

This code

```
proc export 
  data=sashelp.prdsale 
  dbms=xlsx 
  outfile="c:\temp\prdsale.xlsx" 
  replace;
run;
```

is not an option for me as this not authorized for me , im using SASEG

as you may have guessed im not a sas devloper , nor i understand it , im a rpa dev and want to get a solution regarding this shortcut key to open the `save`  window

Comment: So you want some keystroke that will work when running Enterprise Guide?

Comment: yes, that brings up that window